# Making ggdensity plots in a loop with changing variables

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am very new to R so any help is appreciated! I am working with a dataset where I am comparing people with and without HIV based on various factors-- age, BMI, waist/hip ratio, etc. I would like to make the process of doing group comparisons as user-friendly as possible, so I am trying to go through my spreadsheet column by column rather than having to manually select each variable and run all my calculations each time. My tables look something like this.

| HIV | Age | BMI | Waist Circumference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pos | 55 | 28.4 | 49.2 |
| neg | 43 | 33.7 | 37.4 |
| pos | 61 | 38.9 | 43.1 |

I am currently using a for loop (I have read they are not as ideal in R but I am coming from a python background and am not as familiar with the apply functions so I'd like to use a for loop while I'm learning R, and my dataset isn't huge so I think it will be okay). I want to produce density plots for Age, BMI, etc based on HIV status. I am using the ggpubr library for this. Thanks all!!!

```
install.packages("ggpubr")
library("ggpubr")
for (i in 2:ncol(file)){

   ggdensity(file, toString(names(file[i])), 
             main= paste("Density Plot HIV All:",names(file[i]),sep=" "),
             xlab= names(file[i])
    )
} #this works just fine to give me an aggregate plot for HIV+ and HIV- folks

ggdensity(file$Age[HIV=="pos"],
          main="Density Plot HIV All: Age",
          xlab="Age"
          ) #this works just fine to give me a plot with just my HIV positive folks; if I use      
          "file, Age" as above I get the error "Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns
           selected" and I don't really understand why

#When I try to combine the two I get

for (i in 2:ncol(file)){

   ggdensity(file$toString(names(file[i]))[HIV=="pos"], 
             main= paste("Density Plot HIV All:",names(file[i]),sep=" "),
             xlab= names(file[i])
    )
} #"Error in ggdensity(file$toString(names(file[i]))[HIV == "pos"], main = paste("Density Plot HIV Positive:",  :attempt to apply non-function"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the way you are trying to subset the data. Additionally you could make your life easier and your code cleaner by directly looping over column names:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

cols <- names(file)[-1]
for (col in cols) {
  p <- ggdensity(file[file$HIV == "pos", ],
    x = col,
    main = paste("Density Plot HIV All:", col, sep = " "),
    xlab = col
  )
  print(p)
}
```

[image][image][image]

**DATA**

```
file <- data.frame(
  HIV = c("pos", "neg", "pos"),
  Age = c(55L, 43L, 61L),
  BMI = c(28.4, 33.7, 38.9),
  Waist.Circumference = c(49.2, 37.4, 43.1)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's really helpful I appreciate it! I ended up needing two slightly different functions-- for aggregate: ggdensity(file, column, main=x, xlab=y), for HIV+ ggdensity(file[column][HIV=="pos",], main=x, lab=y) , I had no idea how important the trailing comma was :)